# Como localizar uma informação considerando uma range (intervalo de números)

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-excel

Na empresa onde trabalho estamos automatizando o processo de calculo da remuneração variável, e para tal estamos transpondo toda a lógica que estava no **EXCEL** para o banco de dados. Porem estou com uma certa dificuldade.

Tenho uma tabela com informações que são utilizadas como parâmetros para bonificar o colaborador dependendo da sua performance.

[image: TABELA FATOR]

Por exemplo: o colaborador atingiu um **Fator de 14.78**. Neste caso ele ficaria na linha 4 (BASE: 12.64920 | TETO: 25.29830), logo seu bônus seria de 57,14%. No **EXCEL** para buscar o percentual de bônus eu simplesmente faria um PROCV utilizando a **correspondência aproximada**.

No SQL Server estou tentando fazer o mesmo, porem sem sucesso. Tentei um INNER JOIN com BETWEEN, obviamente não deu certo.

Abaixo está a tabela com a performance do colaborador. A partir da coluna ENTREGA tenho que ir na tabela de FATOR, observar o intervalo (BASE e TETO) e achar o percentual de BÔNUS correspondente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nao entendi direito. A bonificaçao dele nao deveria ser 57,14%?
Tem como mostrar a tabela com a qual você estava querendo fazer o inner join?

Comment: Corrigi! Deve ser 57,14% a bonificação. Basicamente tenho que trazer a informação da coluna BONUS levando em considerando as informações de BASE e TETO (base é o inicio do intervalo e teto é o fim do intervalo)

Comment: Coloca no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) como ta a construção das tabelas, faz uns insert de exemplos, isso ajuda muito entender a estrutura do teu banco e a responder tua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a faixa está na mesma linha da tabela, pode usar o `BETWEEN` para encontrar o valor da entrega entre base e teto:

```
select dados.nome, parametros.bonus
  from dados, parametros
 where dados.entrega between parametros.base and parametros.teto
```

Neste exemplo, chamei a primeira tabela de parametros e a segunda de dados. Aproveitei o `BETWEEN` para fazer o `JOIN` das tabelas, já que elas não tem chave que se relacione.

Veja o exemplo funcionando aqui: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/947fe/1)

Answer (score 0):

Sem as tuas tabelas fica meio difícil responder.
Se tu tiver uma tabela exatamente igual a esse excel e uma tabela com o fator do colaborador, da para tentar algo assim

`SELECT fat.bonus 
 FROM tabela_fator fat,(SELECT cola.entrega FROM tabela_colaborador cola) AS entrega
 WHERE entrega>=fat.base AND entrega<=fat.teto`